# Public dataset of YouTube videos for analysis on views

Tags: social-media

I am planning on doing a data analysis on YouTuBe videos across multiple users. Specifically, I want to see what drives views and am looking for a public dataset or a way to collect data on YouTuBe videos. I want a dataset consists of views (video's views), video length, video age, ratings, comments, tags, categories and other factors that might affect views.

So far, I have found this data set http://netsg.cs.sfu.ca/youtubedata/ which is great for my analysis. However, the data only goes until 2008 and I would like to have a more recent set of data. Something similar would work well for my projects.

EDIT: I found this large dataset [Trending YouTube Video Statistics and Comments](https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube/data) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this large dataset [Trending YouTube Video Statistics and Comments](https://www.kaggle.com/datasnaek/youtube/data) in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 0):

I've added some steps to collect views and ratings from playlists or channels, or simple lists of youtube videos.

The example is done for Last Week Tonight with John Oliver (HBO) but could be adapted.

Processing requires [youtube-dl](https://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/), [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), and python 3.7+

**Raw data:** https://gist.github.com/philshem/ca0b8f964458c63ee4f0e68c0f700f39#file-all-csv

**youtube-dl wrapper** (may be time-outs): https://gist.github.com/philshem/ca0b8f964458c63ee4f0e68c0f700f39#file-get_stats-sh

**python json2csv:** https://gist.github.com/philshem/ca0b8f964458c63ee4f0e68c0f700f39#file-make_csv-py

**sample json for one video:** https://gist.github.com/philshem/ca0b8f964458c63ee4f0e68c0f700f39#file-sample-json

---

based on this tweet of mine: https://twitter.com/philshem/status/1295725064147603459